# Else/If input isn't printing the correct response

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

The program asks the user questions and responds accordingly. I am using ArrayLists with if statements to accomplish this. I cannot understand why my else/if code is not working. When I respond with "North Carolina" I always receive the final response of "I would have never guessed!"

```
System.out.print("Where are you from? ");
    states.add(scanner.next());

    if (states.contains("Florida") || states.contains("florida")) {
        System.out.println("So was I!\n");
    } else {
    if (states.contains("North Carolina") || states.contains("north carolina")) {
        System.out.println("I hear that's a nice place to live.\n");
    } else {
            System.out.println("I would have never guessed!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm no java expert but why do you have a nested if statement? I think if statements should only have one `else` and if you're doing an `else if (blah) { doSomething }` it should be that and not `else { if (blah) { doSomething } }`.

Comment: Your nesting is incorrect, which is a good example of why you should avoid nesting if statements to begin with when it can be avoided.

Comment: I'm not sure what `scanner` does, but could it perhaps read only one word, so you get "North"? Or does it read the whole line including newline, so you get "North Carolina\n"?

Comment: @Arndt Jonasson Thank you! That just made me realize that is what the problem is. Any idea how I get it to read multiple words? I tried adding a + between them but didn't work.

Comment: I don't know how `scanner` works. Better ask a new question now that we have the if/else issue out of the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nesting is incorrect. When you start writing bigger more complex programs, you will learn to simplify your code for readability. Any time you have a bunch of `if` and `if else` statements the code can quickly become difficult to read/ and or debug. This is how I would write it.

```
 public static static void main(String args[]){
       List<String> states = new ArrayList<>();
       whereAreYouFrom(states);
    }

   public static void whereAreYouFrom(List<String> states){
           System.out.print("Where are you from? ");
           states.add(scanner.next());

            if (states.contains("Florida") || states.contains("florida")) {
              System.out.println("So was I!\n");
               return;
             }

            if (states.contains("North Carolina") || states.contains("north carolina")){ 
                System.out.println("I hear that's a nice place to live.\n");
                return;
             }

            System.out.println("I would have never guessed!");
      }
```

If you want to get fancy, you can use a `switch` statement, but honestly the above way will probably be the most helpful to you for debugging in the future.

Comment: I'm a little confused. When I alter the code as you said, the line: public void whereAreYouFrom(){ gives me an error (illegal start of expression). When I do everything but that part, I just get the same result as before. What am I missing here? Sorry, very inexperienced.

Comment: That's because you need to put `public void whereAreYouFrom()` inside of some class. You probably have a `main` class that you're working with. In which case you need to put the entire `public static void whereAreYouFrom()` method inside of the `main` class, making sure that you keep the braces in tact. Don't fret, you'll get it.

Comment: Heh, now I'm very confused, but I feel like I'm close. You're saying that what you wrote above should be in the main class, and another class should somehow run it? I wasn't aware that I would need multiple classes for this.

Comment: What I was saying is that the method `public void whereAreYouFrom()` cant exist on it's own. It has to be inside of some `class`. In your case, it's most likely the main class. My answer above shows how the method should go inside of the `main` class

Comment: any idea why I'm still getting "I would have never guessed!" for "North Carolina"? The code looks much better, but I still have the original issue.

Comment: @jonathan The only thing I can think of is that you have some whitespace on your input. try using `trim()` on your user input. i.e `String trimedInput = scanner.next().trim();`